# Conversion between Tuple<T1,T2> and KeyValuePair<T1, T2>

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there any built in conversion or cast between `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` and `Tuple<T1, T2>`?

I know this would be a trivial extension method:

```
public static KeyValuePair<T1, T2> ToPair<T1, T2>(this Tuple<T1, T2> source)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T1, T2>(source.Item1, source.Item2);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2> ToTuple<T1, T2>(this KeyValuePair<T1, T2> source)
{
    return Tuple.Create(source.Key, source.Value);
}
```

But since objects can be used for similar purposes (especially since `KeyValuePair<>` was often used in place of a 2 element `Tuple<>` until it's addition to C#4.0), I was wondering if such a converter was already built into the framework?

Reason I ask is I am working with an older library (targeting .NET 3.5) that used `KeyValuePair<>` in many places that a Tuple might be more appropriate, and I want to use `Tuple<>` in the new code.  so I'm trying to figure out if I can just cast or convert the return `kvp` values from these methods to `Tuple` or if I need to define my own conversion (or change the older code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in conversion in the BCL that I'm aware of, and there's definitely no implicit or explicit cast. I doubt they'd ever add this conversion because the types are used for different purposes.

I think your version is fine.